# Spring Async method or event throws HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext() exception

Tags: hystrix, spring-async

Our code has a few @Async methods, and ApplicationListeners. These classes and methods end up calling API services that have the @Hystrix annotation. These calls throw the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext() must be called at the beginning of each request before RequestVariable functionality can be used.
at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixRequestVariableDefault.get(HystrixRequestVariableDefault.java:76) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixRequestVariableHolder.get(HystrixRequestVariableHolder.java:68) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixRequestLog.getCurrentRequest(HystrixRequestLog.java:85) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand.<init>(AbstractCommand.java:274) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.<init>(HystrixCommand.java:142) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.<init>(HystrixCommand.java:128) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.AbstractHystrixCommand.<init>(AbstractHystrixCommand.java:55) ~[hystrix-javanica-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.GenericCommand.<init>(GenericCommand.java:33) ~[hystrix-javanica-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.GenericHystrixCommandFactory.create(GenericHystrixCommandFactory.java:32) ~[hystrix-javanica-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.GenericHystrixCommandFactory.create(GenericHystrixCommandFactory.java:21) ~[hystrix-javanica-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.command.AbstractHystrixCommandFactory.create(AbstractHystrixCommandFactory.java:78) ~[hystrix-javanica-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
at com.netflix.hystrix.contrib.javanica.aop.aspectj.HystrixCommandAspect.methodsAnnotatedWithHystrixCommand(HystrixCommandAspect.java:81) ~[hystrix-javanica-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168) [spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) ~[spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
at com.intuit.platform.common.aop.InstrumentationAspect.profile(InstrumentationAspect.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor204.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
```

Adding HystrixRequestContext.initializeContext() in the Async method does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the value before the request sends.
Override HystrixRequestVariableDefault

For more info this issue on Github: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/895

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.